# grunt-contrib-watch with livereload with vs without grunt-contrib-connect

Tags: node.js, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-connect

I am new to Node,grunt and I use both grunt-contrib-watch and grunt-contrib-connect.

As far as I understand, watch task with livereload = true option reruns the mentioned tasks of the target and refreshes the browser by triggering a livereload server to serve reloaded static files.

However, if browser reload and static file serve happens with just watch task with livereload=true option, why do we need grunt-contrib-connect again for the same job.

- Please explain whether we need connect task still to serve this purpose or is it for something else.
- Did I understand right with regards to achieving the goal with just watch with livereload=true.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opetion of `livereload` in `grunt-contrib-watch` is responsible to trigger websocket request to browser to reload the page. It is not a http server. From what i remember `grunt-contrib-connect` is simply an `HTTP server`. Remember that `grunt-contrib-watch` starts websocket server at port **35736** so add the script

```
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

To trigger live reload in browser.

Hope this clarifies what you need

Comment: Whenever any css/js files modified, if I can re-run the tasks, reload the files in the server, do a page refresh with just watch with liverreload option and livereload.js in place, then I am not sure what for I need grunt-contrib-connect again? Coz, typically that's what all is needed with regards to static files. Please correct me/clarify. Thank you.

Comment: @Madav i think what you mean is directly open files in browser, which would work fine i guess. In my cases usually i develop single page applications, so there is some ammount of server routing needed. Thats why the need for `http server`. Not saying it can't be done without it but the proper way is to use server. Also you are not limited to define a server in grunt, i usually end up using a third party server like nginx etc even for my dev code :)

Comment: Yeah I understand the need for http server.. However, for open static files, is it fare to think that watch-liverreload option alone is sufficient for the job done? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah sure. But i would recommend a server as that is the final environment that the code is supposed to be served in (y)